# If $\|u\|=1\geq \|v\|$, proof that if $w = \frac{v}{\|v\|}$, $\|u+w\|^2 + b\|u-w\|^2 < 4$.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $b\geq 1$ and let $\|u\| = 1 \geq \|v\|$ in a Banach Space $V$ such that $$\|u+v\|^2 + (4b+1)\|u-v\| < 2+2\|v\|^2 \quad (1)$$
I'm trying to proof that if $w = \frac{v}{\|v\|}$, $$\|u+w\|^2 + b\|u-w\|^2 < 4$$

My attempt:

By triangle inequality in $(1)$, 
$$ (4b+1)\|u-v\|^2 < 2 + 2\|v\|^2 - \|u+v\|^2 \leq (1+\|v\|)^2 $$
and
$$ \|u+w\|^2 \leq \|u+v\|^2 + \|w-v\|^2 + 2\|u+v\|\,\|w-v\| \leq \|u+v\|^2 + \|w-v\|^2 + 2 (1-\|v\|^2) $$

Then, 
$$ \|u+w\|^2 + b\|u-w\|^2 < \|u+v\|^2 + \|w-v\|^2 + 2 (1-\|v\|^2) + b\|u-w\|^2 $$

My idea is proof that $b\|u-w\|^2 + \|w-v\|^2 \leq (4b+1) \|u-v\|^2$ and, in afirmative case, the exercise would be complete. However, I don't know how to verify this inequality. I'd appreciate a hint to proof it or another idea to the exercise.

Any help?